# Manipulate owl file using Protege-OWL API.(delete classes,delete properties)

Tags: class, owl, protege, object-property

I need to manipulate owl file using the Protege-Owl API. You know, creating classes and properties isn't too difficult.But I don't know how to delete a class or property.If we treat the owl file as a graph, deleting an class means deleting an node and its direct edge.For exemple:

```
<owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&data;DataBundle"/>
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&data;DataItem"/>
</owl:unionOf>
```

if I want to delete the class DataItem,

1. how should I do it using Protege-OWL API? Does RDFResource.delete()can achieve this? I have tried it,but I can't achieve this,maybe there is something wrong.
2. what will I get after I delete the DataItem?
3. If DataItem is the domain of an property, what will I get after I delete it?

I hope to get your answer.

Edit: the Protege OWL API is the api described [here](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/ProtegeOWL_API_Programmers_Guide), not the OWL API described [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi).

Comment: I think you'll need to show at least some of your code.  You mention that you've used RDFResource#delete, but that it didn't work.  How did you use it?  What didn't work about it?

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/27371/manipulate-owl-file-using-protege-owl-apidelete-classesdelete-properties

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Today I tried to fix my code,and now it works well.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem.  Can you add some comments to the code in your answer to show people what the difference is?  Also, please [accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) to let other users know that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joshua Taylor,Thank you for your answer!I'm a new user and I make a mistake for posting this problem twice.Sorry for that.I make some mistakes in my code at first and today I tried to fix it.The following codes can delete a class or property.

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.Reader;
 import java.net.URI;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.RDFResource;

 public class DeleteClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //get model from an owl file
    String filePath = "D:\\ss.owl";
    FileInputStream inFile= new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inFile,"UTF-8");
    JenaOWLModel jenaOwlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromReader(in);
    //get an class from the model
    RDFResource oneClass=jenaOwlModel.getRDFResource("Person");
    RDFResource oneDataProperty=jenaOwlModel.getRDFResource("age");
    //delete the resource
    oneClass.delete();
    oneDataProperty.delete();
    //save the model to another owl file
    URI file=URI.create("file:///D:/ssChange.owl");
    System.out.println(file);
    jenaOwlModel.save(file);
    //System.out.println(oneClass);

}

}
```